# Weird Samba username mapping

Tags: permissions, samba, shared-folders

I have a very weird problem with Samba and username map.
The mapping file is like this:

```
username map = /etc/samba/users.map
```

Contents of /etc/samba/users.map:

```
master = johndoe user2 user3
regular = johndoe user5 user6
restricted = johndoe user8 user9
```

The problem is that Samba always maps `johndoe` to the last local user listed in `/etc/samba/users.map` file. In the example above, `johndoe` will always be mapped to `restricted`, so if I have a share that allows only `master` and anohter share that allows only `restricted`, I will not be able to access both, although `johndoe` is listed in both entries.

Is this a normal behaviour or not?

Comment: @matigo Yes, the goal is to have johndoe access some shares that other users can. If these shares intersect, how should I make the lists so I don't get the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Correct. This is by design. From [the documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#USERNAMEMAP):

> The map file is parsed line by line. Each line should contain a single UNIX username on the left then a '=' followed by a list of usernames on the right. The list of usernames on the right may contain names of the form @group in which case they will match any UNIX username in that group. The special client name '*' is a wildcard and matches any name. Each line of the map file may be up to 1023 characters long.
>
> The file is processed on each line by taking the supplied username and comparing it with each username on the right hand side of the '=' signs. If the supplied name matches any of the names on the right hand side then it is replaced with the name on the left. Processing then continues with the next line.

As a result, having the same user account appear in multiple lines will not include them in every map, but in the last map defined.

If the goal is to have a “super user”, then you may need to look at [share-specific lists](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html) or mapping account *groups* rather than users.